# GoType issues with SublimeLinter

Tags: go, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm a bit new to Go, and I've been trying to use the [SublimeLinter-contrib-gotype](https://github.com/sirreal/SublimeLinter-contrib-gotype) package to lint my files. It works well for the most part, but for some reason it throws an error if I try to import a Go package from GitHub. I've been trying to use the simple example from the [Echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo/) framework. When I run the code, it works fine but for some reason the linter is causing issues.

It throws an error saying:

> could not import github.com/labstack/echo (can't find import: )

I've already run the `go get github.com/labstack/echo` command, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

I've attached a screenshot as well:

[image]

And [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9042391f756a1c993124) is a link to the code I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd faced the same problem. Try running

`launchctl setenv GOPATH $GOPATH`

and restarting ST, this won't work after a reboot.

[Source](https://github.com/alecthomas/SublimeLinter-contrib-gometalinter/issues/1)

If you use Go Sublime, the following should work better.

Sublime Text menu > Preferences > Package Settings > GoSublime > Settings - Default / User

```
"shell": ["/usr/bin/bash"],
"env": {"GOPATH": "/Users/username/gopath/"},
```